# GMap.NET get longitude and latitude

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps

First time using GMaps.NET and I'm stuck at one part.

I have a list of addresses that I need to get the longitude and latitude for, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

So I need to go from "111 Test Street, Example City, Earth" to -123,55.

I tried using `GMap.NET.GeocodingProvider;`but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked it out in case anyone else has the same issue.

I just did a webrequest to google which gives me what I needed.

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address +" +View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false");
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```